# unhandled exception widget with sdkTrays in Ogre

Tags: c++, ogre3d

I have some serious issues with sdkTrays in Ogre.

I have my OgreKinectGame that inherits from BaseApplication. BaseApplication is creating logo etc. using sdkTrayManager. I thought this mTrayMgr was inherited and can be used in my application as well.

I am trying to setup widgets for a HUD, but I'm getting unhandled exception errors.

My setupWidgets() function looks like this.

```
void OgreKinectGame::setupWidgets()
```

{

```
if(!mTrayMgr)
    mTrayMgr = new SdkTrayManager("InterfaceName", mWindow, mMouse);

    //mTrayMgr->destroyAllWidgets(); this caused exceptions as well
    // create check boxes to toggle the visibility of our particle systems
    const int WIDTH_UI = 160;
    // main menu
    mTrayMgr->createLabel(TL_CENTER, "mMainMenuLabel", "Main Menu", WIDTH_UI);
    mTrayMgr->createButton(TL_CENTER, "mOptionButton", "Option");
    mTrayMgr->createButton(TL_CENTER, "mCreditButton", "About");
    mTrayMgr->createButton(TL_CENTER, "mQuitButton", "Quit");

    mTrayMgr->showAll();
```

}
[image: Unhandled exception]

Comment: Can your application successfully load the SdkTrays.zip archive that contains all the GUI related resources? If not, that might be the reason why the cursor access is causing trouble. Check for errors/exceptions in your Ogre.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, where did you initialize your setupWidgets()? , on BaseApplication class, they have setup(), you can create a virtual of this setup() to your main class and then initialize your setupWiget() there, e.g.,

```
bool OgreKinectGame::setup(void)
{
   if (!BaseApplication::setup()) {
    return false;
   }
   // Load fonts for tray captions
   FontManager::getSingleton().getByName("SdkTrays/Caption")->load();
   setupWidgets();//initialize here for your setupWidget()
}
```

second, I think your setupWidget() should be like this,

```
void OgreKinectGame::setupWidgets()
{
    const int WIDTH_UI = 160;
    // main menu
    mTrayMgr->createLabel(TL_CENTER, "mMainMenuLabel", "Main Menu", WIDTH_UI);
    mTrayMgr->createButton(TL_CENTER, "mOptionButton", "Option");
    mTrayMgr->createButton(TL_CENTER, "mCreditButton", "About");
    mTrayMgr->createButton(TL_CENTER, "mQuitButton", "Quit");
}
```

Can you try this solution and back again if still get crash?

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue! I was trying to (unsuccessfully) implement my own setup instead of using the inherited function bool setup() from BaseApplication.